# How to use iOS Keychain to stored an OAuth token on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, ios, oauth, restkit

I am going to use RestKit to access web api using OAuth. In the [RestKit doc raecommendations](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/OAuth-Support-on-RestKit):

> We strongly encourage you to keep access_token, refresh_token,
>   clientId and clientSecret using the iOS Keychain or other secure
>   storage ways.

How can I use `iOS Keychain` to store a secret token?

UPDATE: This question is down-voted. Probably I didn't make my question clear enough. I *knew* there is iOS Keychain and the APIs. My question is how to store a `token` in a  secret place (using iOS Keychain or other encryption lib) before the app is shipped, without a plain text version stored some where else (in code or in plist). As it is an api token, which is not supposed to be entered by user, how can I initialize the token in the first place.

Comment: I think you should rewrite your question.

Answer (score 1):

We store the various components (accessToken, refreshToken, etc.) inside a token class that conforms to the NSCoding protocol.  We then archive the object and store it in the keychain as a string.

Our TokenModel protocol looks like this:

```
@protocol TokenModel <NSCoding, NSObject>

@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *accessToken;
@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSDate *expirationDate;
@property(nonatomic, assign, readonly) NSTimeInterval expiresIn;
@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *refreshToken;
@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *tokenType;

- (BOOL)isAccessTokenExpired;

@end
```

We use a keychain service helper that lets us access the keychain as simply as NSUserDefaults, with the same requirement that stored objects must conform to the NSCoding protocol.

```
@protocol KeychainService <NSObject>

- (id)objectForKey:(id)key error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error;
- (BOOL)setObject:(id)object forKey:(id)key error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error;

- (BOOL)removeObjectForKey:(id)key error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error;

@end
```